# C++ Inheritance without virtual destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance

If the parent class's destructor is not virtual, but the subclass has no additional members, is it safe to use the parent class's destructor?

```
class A{
    ~A();
    protected:
        int i;
};
class B: public A{

}

A *x = new B; delete x;
```

Comment: In practice you might get away with it, but nobody's going to guarantee it. Remember that one possible outcome of undefined behavior is to work exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe, it's undefined behaviour as per §5.3.5

> #### 5.3.5 Delete [expr.delete]
>
> <sup>3</sup> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

An example of *why* it could break is this:

```
class A
{
public:
    ~A();
protected:
    int i;
};

class B: public A
{
    virtual void dummy();
}

A *x = new B; delete x;
```

Now `B` has a vtbl and hence the object layout is different.

And BTW: `public class A` is Java or some other language, but not C++.

Comment: "but the subclass has no additional members"

Comment: @citykid I understand the OP to mean "no additional member variables". But you could also use `virtual ~B() {}` (if you accept this as not an *additional* member). Anyways, it doesn't matter. The standard says it's UB, and so it is.

Comment: I certainly would recommend the virtual ctor in all cases, but a member is a member. Your case is certainly undefined and in practice problematic as you say.

Comment: Also, a virtual dtor makes the derived type a *polymorphic type*, such that `dynamic_cast` can work. `dynamic_cast<void*>(x)` may be required (is?) depending on the implementation of the delete-expression (it will call a deallocation function that takes a `void*`).

Answer (score 3):

the short answer is no, it is unsafe.

Comment: Why do you think so? I would say this restricted case is safe.

Comment: Because The Committee said it's unsafe. A compiler is not required to emit code that performs correctly if you do that. That's what "undefined behavior" means.

Comment: but note that here x is of type A*.

Comment: The pointer is of type A*, yes, but the dynamic type of what is being pointed to is B.

Answer (score 0):

Why take the risk?

A few bytes to ensure that the base classes get destroyed as well is not that big of a hit.

Prevents memory leaks as well.